# Checar se um elemento de um array está contido em cada elemento de outra array com php

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho duas arrays, preciso pegar cada elemento da segunda array e checar se está contido em algum elemento da primeira array usando, por exemplo, a função strpos().

Ou seja, preciso verificar se alguma **string** da lista 2 está contida em alguma **URL** da lista 1. Desde já agradeço.

```js
<?php
$ads = array();
$ads[0] = "https://superman.com.br";
$ads[1] = "https://photoshop.com.br?galid=";
$ads[2] = "https://mercado.com.br";
$ads[3] = "https://xdemais.com.br";
$ads[4] = "https://imagens.com.br";
$ads[5] = "https://terceiraidade.com.br";
$ads[6] = "https://goldenartesgraficas.com.br";
$ads[7] = "https://empregos.com.br";
$ads[8] = "https://umcentavo.com.br";
$ads[9] = "https://classificados.com.br";


 $filter_ads = array();
 $filter_ads[0] = "galid=";
 $filter_ads[1] = "gslid=";
 $filter_ads[2] = "ghlid=";
 $filter_ads[3] = "gplid=";
 $filter_ads[4] = "gulid=";
 $filter_ads[5] = "gllid=";
 $filter_ads[6] = "gklid=";
 $filter_ads[7] = "grlid=";
 $filter_ads[8] = "gwlid=";
 $filter_ads[9] = "gelid="; 

foreach($ads as $ads_x) {
    if (strpos($ads_x, in_array($filter_ads, $ads))) {
     echo "Existe";
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percorra os 2 arrays em busca de uma ocorrência:

```
foreach ($ads as $link) {

    foreach ($filter_ads as $ads) {

        if (strpos($link, $ads)){
            echo "Achei aqui: <br />"
            . "Link: ". $link ." <br />"
            . "parametro: ". $ads ."<br /><br />";
        }

    }

}
```

Você ainda pode testar essas outras 2 opções, dependendo da sua necessidade elas podem resolver. Nos 2 casos transformei o array de links em uma grande string separada por virgula apenas para procurar uma ocorrência do filtro:

Assim ela retornará 1 se encontrar e 0 se não encontrar:

```
foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
    echo preg_match("/". $filter ."/", implode(",", $ads));
}
```

Assim ele retornará a posição em que se encontra a ocorrência, isso se houver ocorrência:

```
foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
    echo strpos(implode(",", $ads), $filter);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: PERFEITO!!! Valeu Thomas Lima, muito grato pela a ajuda.